# Way to export a "post processed" makefile

Tags: makefile

Say that you have have a makefile.

Is there a way to get the post-processed output of it without running it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the makefile with all variables expanded? Because much of the output comes from the shell commands.

Comment: Yes, essentially.  Or something close.  I figure since makefiles have existed for quite a long time, some sort of approximation might exist?

Comment: The closest you can get today is the output of `make -p`.  However, this won't give you a straightforward, runnable makefile that's equivalent to the original (or it might, but it's not guaranteed to do so).